# Rails production error: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: photoshop-drop-shadow

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing this photoshop-drop-shadow while running my Rails 4.2 application in production mode.

> ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable:
>   photoshop-drop-shadow. Load paths:
>   /home/abcuser/Desktop/project/Myproject/app/assets/images
>   /home/abcuser/Desktop/project/Myproject/app/assets/javascripts
>   /home/abcuser/Desktop/project/Myproject/app/assets/stylesheets
>   /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.4.0/app/assets/javascripts
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.4.0/app/assets/source
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/tinymce-rails-4.4.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/remotipart-1.2.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/bourbon-4.2.7/app/assets/stylesheets
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/css3buttons-1.0.1/lib/assets/images
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/css3buttons-1.0.1/lib/assets/stylesheets
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/client_side_validations-4.2.5/vendor/assets/javascripts
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/images
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/javascripts
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-ui-rails-5.0.5/app/assets/stylesheets
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
>
> /home/abcuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets):
>
> ```
>  5:   <meta charset="UTF-8">
>  6:   <title><%= Rails.application.config.custom.app_name %></title>
>  7:   <%#= stylesheet_link_tag "marketing" %>
>  8:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
>  9:     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/marketing/css/vendor/bootstrap.css">
> 10:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/marketing/css/all.css">
> 11:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/marketing/css/colorbox.css">
> ```
>
> app/assets/stylesheets/report.scss.erb:6
>   app/views/layouts/public.html.erb:8:in
>   `_app_views_layouts_public_html_erb__559746694008157479_39976240'

These are my 1st 9 lines in the report.scss.erb:

```
/* We broke this out of default.css file becuase it inteferring with siilar classes that were overloaded by another dev for the new version of the report/nudge show view */

@import "compass";
@import "bourbon";
@import "photoshop-drop-shadow";
                                               #this is the line it is showing error.
#master-photos-container{height:485px;margin-top:20px;}
#photos #paging-left {float:left;height:205px;width:21px;padding-top:185px;padding-left:15px;}
#photos #paging-right {float:left;height:205px;width:21px;padding-top:185px;}
```

I am including report.css in application.css as:

```
 *= require report
```

It is working fine in development mode, I don't know why it is not running production mode.
I am very much worried home page, please help.

Comment: Have a look at the asset pipeline! The css file is most probably not found because it does not have the right path! You should use something like stylesheet_link_tag

Comment: Wait, are you using css or scss?

Comment: Your file should be `report.scss` not `reports.scss.erb`.

What does "photoshop-drop-shadow' look like and where is it located? What is the ending? css or scss? should be scss!

Comment: Are you preloading assets?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production read this! From there: If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array in config/initializers/assets.rb:
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']